# Push to Dockerhub sends entire image instead of just the changes

Tags: docker, dockerhub

I am just starting with Docker.  I downloaded an image.  I made some changes and pushed it to my public repository on Dockerhub.  From the size of the data pushed, it seemed like the entire image was transmitted.

I made some small changes and committed a new version of my image.  I pushed again, and again, a large amount of data (500 MiB) was transmitted.

I thought that docker would only send the changes I made.  Am I missing something?  Is there something I need to do so only the changes are pushed each time instead of a large image?

Comment: Are you changing via modifying the `Dockerfile` or via `docker commit`? You can get a little more information on the layers with `docker history <image name>`, it may be of some use.

Comment: @WillHogan I am using `docker commit`.  The history command is useful.  It shows when I installed matplotlib (python module) it took 764.7 MB.  That seems like a whole lot more than it ought to.  Any way for me to drill in and determine why so big?

Comment: Yes, that doesn't seem right. If I build and image and install matplotlib it adds 118.2 MB.  You could `docker diff` on the container before you `docker commit` and it will display changed/added files, which may or may not provide some more insight.